# redirecionamento de formulario usando javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, formulário, front-end

tenho um formulário com as suas validações , ai quero que quando clicar no botão seja redirecionado a uma pagina de agradecimento
esse é o botão em html

```
     <button onclick="thanks()" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" >Enviar</button>
```

e em js eu já fiz uma função porém eu quero apenas quando as validações forem corretas

```
    function thanks(){
    window.location = "thanks.html"
    
}
```

aqui uma parte de como ta o campo das validações

```
function checkInputs(){
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value()
    

     if(firstnameValue === ''){
        errorValidation(firstname, "Preencha essa campo :(")

    }else{
        successValidation(firstname)
    }
}
```

**tem mais campos porém vou deixar so esse como exemplo**

Answer (score -1):

O que você pode fazer é colocar tudo isso em uma única função. Segue um exemplo:

```
function validateAndSend(){
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value()
    

     if(!firstnameValue){
        errorValidation(firstname, "Preencha essa campo :(")

     } else {
        successValidation(firstname);
        window.location = "thanks.html"
    }
}
```

Observação: O ponto de exclamação inverte um valor booleano(true/false), ou seja, caso o firstName esteja vazio colocando o ! antes irá retornar que está vazio, que não há valor, caso colocasse somente if(firstName) estaria dizendo "se firstName existir..." mas colocando if(!firstName) você vai estar dizendo "se firstName não existir...". No else irá usar a função successValidation e em seguida redirecionar para a página de agradecimento

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).